# Angular ControlValueAccessor's WriteValue method doesn't trigger ngModelChange

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using a primeng p-spinner control which is just a custom control(number type input control) in angular. It also implements the WriteValue() method. But when the value changes, it doesn't trigger the ngModelChange event.

```
<p-spinner #startSpinner size="6" [ngModel]="someValue"
                        (ngModelChange)="someMethod($event)" [min]="0"
                        styleClass="numberRangeSpinner"></p-spinner>
```

But it gets triggered for my own custom control:

```
<custom-input #input [ngModel]="someValue"
                      (ngModelChange)="someMethod($event)" 
                      ></custom-input>
```

Unable to figure out what is wrong here. Both the controls implement the ControlValueAccessor class.

Comment: Please share your ts code

Comment: if the someValue variable changed ngModelChange won't trigger because this is 1-way-binding, try using [(ngModel)] instead (this may happen because ngModelChange is the @Output of ngModel directive

Comment: How are you changing the value? I did some quick testing and it seems to work fine on my end.

Comment: @JamalSalman `[(ngModel)]` is the shorthand for `[ngModel] (ngModelChange)`. Both are completely valid and will work.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren Oh good to know!

Comment: the write method is to pass the value model-->your custom form control. To pass the changes in custom form control --> to model, you need add the method `registerOnChange(fn: any): void { this.change = fn;} `and call to this function with the value inside your custom form, e.g. this.change('hi')

Comment: both control's implementations have registerOnChange()

Comment: Caught the issue. In my custom-input control, modelChange is being called from the value setter as well (even when the new value is same a old value) whereas primeng control calls modelChange only when the value changes.